# Clojure: Store and Compile Large Derived Data Structure

Tags: serialization, clojure, compilation, tree, flat-file

I have a large data structure, a tree, that takes up about 2gb in ram.  It includes clojure sets in the leaves, and refs as the branches.  The tree is built by reading and parsing a large flat file and inserting the rows into the tree.  However this takes about 30 seconds.  Is there a way I can build the tree once, emit it to a clj file, and then compile the tree into my standalone jar so I can lookup values in the tree without re-reading the large text file?  I think this will trim out the 30 second tree build, but also this will help me deploy my standalone jar without needing the text file to come along for the ride.

My first swing at this failed:

```
(def x (ref {:zebra (ref #{1 2 3 4})}))
#<Ref@6781a7dc: {:zebra #<Ref@709c4f85: #{1 2 3 4}>}>

(def y #<Ref@6781a7dc: {:zebra #<Ref@709c4f85: #{1 2 3 4}>}>)
RuntimeException Unreadable form  clojure.lang.Util.runtimeException (Util.java:219)
```

Comment: If it's meant to be a read-only structure, then I would suggest avoiding the `ref`s entirely. They will slow down access, make serialisation trickier as well as making the overall structure use more memory. immutable persistent data structures are your friend.... use them!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Embedding data this big in compiled code may not be possible because of size limits imposed upon the JVM. In particular, no single method may exceed 64 KiB in length. Embedding data in the way I describe further below also necessitates including tons of stuff in the class file it's going to live in; doesn't seem like a great idea.

Given that you're using the data structure read-only, you can construct it once, then emit it to a `.clj` / `.edn` (that's for [edn](https://github.com/edn-format/edn), the serialization format based on Clojure literal notation), then include that file on your class path as a "resource", so that it's included in the überjar (in `resources/` with default Leiningen settings; it'll then get included in the überjar unless excluded by `:uberjar-exclusions` in `project.clj`) and read it from the resource at runtime at full speed of Clojure's reader:

```
(ns foo.core
  (:require [clojure.java.io :as io]))

(defn get-the-huge-data-structure []
  (let [r   (io/resource "huge.edn")
        rdr (java.io.PushbackReader. (io/reader r))]
    (read r)))

;; if you then do something like this:

(def ds (get-the-huge-data-structure))

;; your app will load the data as soon as this namespace is required;
;; for your :main namespace, this means as soon as the app starts;
;; note that if you use AOT compilation, it'll also be loaded at
;; compile time
```

You could also not add it to the überjar, but rather add it to the classpath when running your app. This way your überjar itself would not have to be huge.

Handling stuff other than persistent Clojure data could be accomplished using `print-method` (when serializing) and reader tags (when deserializing). Arthur already demonstrated using reader tags; to use `print-method`, you'd do something like

```
(defmethod print-method clojure.lang.Ref [x writer]
  (.write writer "#ref ")
  (print-method @x writer))

;; from the REPL, after doing the above:

user=> (pr-str {:foo (ref 1)})
"{:foo #ref 1}"
```

Of course you only need to have the `print-method` methods defined when serializing; you're deserializing code can leave it alone, but will need appropriate data readers.

---

Disregarding the code size issue for a moment, as I find the data embedding issue interesting:

Assuming your data structure only contains immutable data natively handled by Clojure (Clojure persistent collections, arbitrarily nested, plus atomic items such as numbers, strings (atomic for this purpose), keywords, symbols; no Refs etc.), you can indeed include it in your code:

```
(defmacro embed [x]
  x)
```

The generated bytecode will then recreate `x` without reading anything, by using constants included in the class file and static methods of the `clojure.lang.RT` class (e.g. `RT.vector` and `RT.map`).

This is, of course, how literals are compiled, since the macro above is a noop. We can make things more interesting though:

```
(ns embed-test.core
  (:require [clojure.java.io :as io])
  (:gen-class))

(defmacro embed-resource [r]
  (let [r   (io/resource r)
        rdr (java.io.PushbackReader. (io/reader r))]
    (read r)))

(defn -main [& args]
  (println (embed-resource "foo.edn")))
```

This will read `foo.edn` at compile time and embed the result in the compiled code (in the sense of including appropriate constants and code to reconstruct the data in the class file). At run time, no further reading will be performed.

Answer (score 3):

If you can structure the tree to be a single value instead of a tree fo references to many values then you would be able to print the tree and read it. Because refs are not readable you won't be able to treat the entire tree as something readable without doing doing your own parsing.

It may be worth looking into using the [extensible reader](https://github.com/edn-format/edn) to add print and read functions for your tree by making it a type.

here is a minimal example of using *data-readers* to produce references to sets and maps from a string:

first define handlers for the contents of each EDN tag/type

```
user> (defn parse-map-ref [m] (ref (apply hash-map m)))
#'user/parse-map-ref
user> (defn parse-set-ref [s] (ref (set s)))
#'user/parse-set-ref
```

Then bind the map *data-readers* to associate the handlers with textual tags:

```
(def y-as-string 
   "#user/map-ref [:zebra #user/set-ref [1 2 3 4]]")

user> (def y (binding [*data-readers* {'user/set-ref user/parse-set-ref
                                       'user/map-ref user/parse-map-ref}]
              (read-string y-as-string)))

user> y
#<Ref@6d130699: {:zebra #<Ref@7c165ec0: #{1 2 3 4}>}>
```

this also works with more deeply nested trees:

```
(def z-as-string 
  "#user/map-ref [:zebra #user/set-ref [1 2 3 4] 
                  :ox #user/map-ref [:amimal #user/set-ref [42]]]")

user> (def z (binding [*data-readers* {'user/set-ref user/parse-set-ref
                                       'user/map-ref user/parse-map-ref}]
               (read-string z-as-string)))
#'user/z
user> z
#<Ref@2430c1a0: {:ox #<Ref@7cf801ef: {:amimal #<Ref@7e473201: #{42}>}>, 
                 :zebra #<Ref@7424206b: #{1 2 3 4}>}>
```

producing strings from trees can be accomplished by extending the print-method multimethod, though it would be a lot easier if you define a type for ref-map and ref-set using deftype so the printer can know which ref should produce which strings.

If in general reading them as strings is too slow there are faster binary serialization libraries like protocol buffers.

Comment: Really, not possible?  I mean in the above example if you change `#<Ref@6781a7dc:` to `(ref` and match the closing `>` it seems like I should be able to compile the tree into my executable.  Why is this non-trivial?

Comment: In the clojure reader types are either "readable" or "not readable" depending on if they can be written to a file and read back. It's a term used by the reader not an opinion on how possible it is to serialize and parse them.

Comment: Understood, thanks.  What I am doing for now is store the data in a text file and read it in, unfortunately that makes my app useless from the command line, needs to be a daemon / server...  I general though I wonder what the right strategy is for including large data structures in a compiled java program...  I've also already run into the 64k limit on method size by coding it in.

Comment: life really will be a lot easier if you can structure it as a tree in a single ref rather than a tree of many refs. Of course this may not be possible directly, though if you can use this form to store it and then convert back to a working form after loading things will likely be a lot easier.

Answer (score 3):

Is this structure something that doesn't change? If not, consider using Java serialization to persist the structure. Deserializing will be much faster than rebuilding every time.

Comment: Yes, this is something made once and then used in a read only fashion.    I wonder, can I compile the serialized object into the target jar and then load it when i run `java -jar treeLookup.jar arg1 arg2`?

Comment: Yes, you can include the serialized object in the target jar and deserialize it either when you need it or when the class gets initialized. I agree with @arthurulfeldt that life will be easier without all the refs.

Comment: Hey can you point me to a reference about how to load it when the class gets initialized?

Comment: Use a class variable: `static final STRUCTURE = methodWhichLoadsStructure()`